# How can I overlay an image (a transparent PNG file) over all the "background" images in a directory using command line?

Tags: command-line, convert, image-processing, png

I have a transparent PNG file (a picture of a cow)

I have a folder that contains images of grass, mountains, rivers and so on.

I want to overlay the cow image onto those background images only by using Linux command line.

Answer (score 5):

## `convert` tool from the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) package

You can `merge` images using [ImageMagick Layering](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#merge)

I.e.:

```sh
convert -page +0+0 grass.jpg \
    -page +256+0 clouds.jpg \
    -page +512+0 cow1.png \
    -background none -layers merge +repage merged.jpg
```

## Batch `convert` several images

Let's suppose that you have two images:
1. `grass.jpg` as first image
2. and `cow1.jpg`, `cow2.jpg` etc as second image to merge

So, your `bash` script is:

```
for image in cow*.jpg; do
  convert -page +0+0 grass.jpg \
    -page +100+100 $image \
    -background none -layers merge +repage $image-merged.jpg
done
```